# Thread-safety of System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket

Tags: .net, clientwebsocket

The [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.websockets.clientwebsocket(v=vs.110).aspx) is unclear about the thread safety of the `System.Net.WebSockets.ClientWebSocket` class.

Is it safe to call the `SendAsync` method from multiple threads simultaneously？

Comment: What is unclear about it? "Any public static (Shared in Visual Basic) members of this type are thread safe. **Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.**" Seems clear to me, so the answer to your question would be no, it does not seem to be safe.

Answer (score 2):

It's thread safe enough to get some work done.

According to the [source](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/d6b11250b5113664dd3701c25bdf9addfacae9cc/src/Common/src/System/Net/WebSockets/ManagedWebSocket.cs#L22-L28) (credit to Michael Kropat for discussing it at https://www.codetinkerer.com/2018/06/05/aspnet-core-websockets.html )

> Thread-safety:
>
> - It’s acceptable to call ReceiveAsync and SendAsync in parallel. One of each may run concurrently.
> - It’s acceptable to have a pending ReceiveAsync while CloseOutputAsync or CloseAsync is called.
> - Attempting to invoke any other operations in parallel may corrupt the instance. Attempting to invoke a send operation while another is in progress or a receive operation while another is in progress will result in an exception.